# ¿Existe una palabra para "Formarse [una persona] en el pensamiento el sonido de algo que no se está oyendo"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Uno de los significados de la palabra visualizar es,

[Visualizar](https://www.google.com/search?q=visualizar%20significado&source=hp&ei=npWuYsKzDP2i1sQPjdSNqAM&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYq6jrlj9MXAJoEN9CULEfM_woq30MtZ8&ved=0ahUKEwjC-vSTx7j4AhV9kZUCHQ1qAzUQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=visualizar%20significado&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAEIAEEEYQ-QEyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBY6CAgAEIAEELEDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARCvAToRCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQ0QMQ1AI6BQgAELEDOgUILhCABDoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6BQgAEMQCUABY8x5g9iBoAHAAeAKAAa4EiAHYFJIBDDAuMTIuMS4wLjEuMZgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)

> Formarse [una persona] en el pensamiento la imagen de algo que no se
> tiene a la vista o de un concepto abstracto.

Quisiera poder usar una palabra similar, pero que haga referencia a formarse en el pensamiento sonidos, no imágenes. ¿Qué palabra debería usar? Pensé que a lo mejor podría usar imaginar, pero no estoy seguro que su significado haga referencia también a sonidos. Por ejemplo, esta definición dice:

[Imaginar](https://www.google.com/search?q=imaginar%20significado&source=hp&ei=55WuYpXiD-Gb1sQP1cOr2AQ&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYq6j98HbYfN1QFzlNW0a_Fz2WQuc8oYb&ved=0ahUKEwjV8d-2x7j4AhXhjZUCHdXhCksQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=imaginar%20significado&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAEIAEEEYQ-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-AogByB-SAQg0LjE4LjQuMZgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)

> Formar en la mente la representación de sucesos, historias o imágenes
> de cosas que no existen en la realidad o que son o fueron reales pero
> no están presentes.

No me queda claro, ¿imaginar hace sólo referencia a imágenes y no a sonidos?

¿Existe una palabra para "Formarse [una persona] en el pensamiento el sonido de algo que no se está oyendo"?

Comment: Cuando se habla de representaciones mentales, las _imágenes_ no son exclusivamente visuales. Es totalmente factible "imaginar sonidos", de hecho lo hacemos siempre. El único problema es que la palabra "imagen" se contamina con su otro significado más concreto y habitual (figura, ilustración, dibujo...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonorizar implica representar con sonido (o música) lo que se narra (cuentos/situaciones), se ve (imágenes) o se siente (emociones/sentimientos) internamente.

Piénsese para este concepto en Beethoven, que articulaba sonidos en su mente y luego era capaz de transcribirlos.

Existen diversas maneras para referirse a este tipo de hechos, que va desde un simple comentario haciendo referencia al interior de la cabeza a un síndrome con tratamiento médico.

Así tenemos;

- Sonorizar un son en el interior de la cabeza
- Alucinaciones musicales
- Sonorizar en la mente sonidos
- Recrear sonidos en la mente
- Oído interno, que recrea mentalmente sonidos
- Oído musical, que recrea mentalmente sonidos
- Imaginería musical
- Melómano interno o sonoro interno
- Síndrome del oído musical

Estas son algunas de las expresiones que se utilizan para aquellas personas que recrean música dentro de su cabeza o interior y que nadie más escucha, a menos que la persona sea capaz y quiera trascribirla.

Comment: De todas la acepciones que se consideran en el DLE para **sonorizar**, me parece que ninguna de ellas encaja.

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre que la palabra más cercana al concepto que se quiere expresar tal vez sea "evocar".

En [esta página](https://www.musicoguia.com/como-evocar-sonidos-de-la-naturaleza-con-body-percussion/) se hace referencia a ejercicios para evocar sonidos de la naturaleza.

> Desde Musicoguía proponemos una sencilla y divertida actividad para realizar en grupo. Vamos a **evocar** el sonido del viento, la lluvia y el trueno utilizando diferentes partes de nuestro cuerpo con Body Percussion.
>
> Con esta actividad desarrollamos la escucha a la vez que exploramos diversos sonidos con nuestro cuerpo. Para realizar la actividad, te proponemos la siguiente secuenciación:
>
> 1º- Comenzamos con el sonido del aire frotando las manos.
>
> 2º- Realizamos el sonido de la lluvia fina con chasquidos.
>
> 3º- El sonido de la lluvia fuerte con golpes alternados en el muslo.
>
> 4º- **Evocamos** el sonido del trueno con un salto alternando los pies.

Answer (score 1):

**> No me queda claro, ¿imaginar hace sólo referencia a imágenes y no a sonidos?


La palabra imaginar puede hacer referencia a sonidos también. La RAE lo define así:**

imaginar
Del lat. imagināri.

1. tr. Representar en la mente la imagen de algo o de alguien. Imagina un campo con flores. U. t. c. prnl. No me la imagino ya con hijos.
2. tr. Suponer algo a partir de ciertos indicios. Imagino que te quedarás a comer. U. t. c. prnl.
3. tr. Inventar o crear algo. He imaginado una forma de solucionar el problema.
4. tr. Concebir algo con la fantasía.

**> ¿Existe una palabra para "Formarse [una persona] en el pensamiento el sonido de algo que no se está oyendo"?


Evocar, creo que puede encajar con lo que buscas.**

En el diccionario de la RAE, la segunda acepción de evocar dice:

2. tr. Dicho de una cosa: Traer algo a la imaginación por asociación de ideas.